# How to select the set of markets (time series) to include in portfolio

Tags: correlation

This question is likely to have been asked before but never answered in a way which I completely understand.

Assume I have some money that I want to invest in a basket of stocks. The investable funds are divided into N equal chunks.

Assume there is a very large number of candidate stocks (10000) in which I could invest.

My goal is to have a relatively balanced portfolio where the correlation/covariance  among the stocks is low.

So, lets say I select IBM as stock 1 of N for my portfolio.

Q1: Now, as I add stocks 2-N to the portfolio, what metric do I use to select the N-1 stocks to keep the portfolio balanced?

Q2: What metric am I trying to minimize/maximize? Correlation, covariance, other?

As there are approximately 10K choices it's not computationally feasible to enumerate all combinations.

Assume that you **can** short a given market that's part of the portfolio.

Comment: Ummm... the metric is the correlation.  (Actually, you are far better off minimizing the *covariance*.)  Another issue is that you can't just enumerate stocks to include in the portfolio: you have to choose *how much* of each one to buy (even when the amounts are quantized into "investable chunks"). In light of this, it's hard to determine your question.  What are you asking about?  The theory of integer programs?  Quadratic optimization?  Modern portfolio theory?  The Capital Asset Pricing Model?

Comment: Assuming the additional variable of how much to buy which will remain relatively uniform over time my question is how to best select a small set of markets to trade from a large set with the goal of portfolio level correlation being low. Maybe, as you said, I should be looking to minimize covariance. I believe I've read that before but wanted to state the problem in a way that made sense to me which is how to select a set of N markets out of a larger set to minimize the desired metric which as you suggest is covariance and not correlation. -- Thanks for your help

Comment: The answer to your reformulated question (which you should incorporate in an edit to the post) depends on whether you can short the assets, so you should indicate whether that is possible.

Comment: When you reply would you provide some insight on why it matters if you can short a given market and how the answer would be different if you could not ... thanks.

Comment: Shorting is a minor issue. The bigger problem is that you don't really know much about portfolio optimization.

Comment: John -agreed that I don't know much about portfolio optimization, hence my question. Am trying to get a handle on this from a perspective that I can understand. Would like it explained to me like I'm the proverbial 5 year old.

Answer (score 2):

Most investment managers are under constraints due to their size and the demands of their clients.

The size constraint can be expressed in terms of liquidity or transaction costs. If a billion dollar fund wanted to invest 1% of its assets in a stock with a 50 million dollar market capitalization, then they would end up owning 20% of the company. Their clients might prefer them to not own more than 5% of the outstanding shares of a company. Moreover, there's no way they could easily enter into that position. They'd have buy in small amounts based on the volume that is traded on the exchange. As a result, many funds will simply due a liquidity screen to narrow down the list of stocks to a more manageable number that they can trade in a more comfortable size.

Your question still stands at this point though. The manager would still need to construct the portfolio. The goals of portfolio construction often come from clients. For instance, your clients want to invest in a large cap U.S. portfolio that with a tracking error constrained to a certain amount. This can be done qualitatively or quantitatively, but you seem to focus on the quantitative approach.

If you are taking a purely quantitative approach, you will be selecting the portfolio through an optimization. In order to limit the portfolio to a fixed number of stocks, the most common approach is mixed integer quadratic programming (MIQP), typically with some sort of branch and bound. It is mixed in the sense that you would be doing integer programming (to implement a binary constraint that implements the cardinality constraint) with quadratic programming (to minimize portfolio variance or whatever). Sometimes this is called cardinality-constrained portfolio optimization. The binary constraint in this case is to sum a series of variables that are 1 if a weight is different from zero.

The method you describe in the question where you invest a fixed amount in each stock is not common, but could, theoretically, be implemented with a different binary constraint. Basically, you would constrain the weights to be 0 or 1/N (If you're including shorts, then you would also add some functionality for that too). Again, this is not common and can only be implemented properly when your optimizer can also handle integer programming.

The downside of MIQP is that it is typically much more time consuming to perform MIQP, particularly as the number of positions increases. One alternative heuristic is to optimize the portfolio without such a constraint, then perform another optimization constraining your set of securities to only a specific number (such as the N largest in the original). You could do this optimization with the same objective or to minimize the tracking error between the ideal portfolio and the security constrained version.

In the above example, where the investor wants a large cap U.S. portfolio with a modest tracking error constraint. Even here there are a number of options. You can set the objective as the portfolio mean with a constraint on the tracking error. Alternately, you can set the objective as some sort of utility.